# How do I copy all the songs off my iPod (nano 4g) to my computer for free

Tags: music, ipod

Okay, here's my issue.

My old computer recently died, and I want to copy all my music from my iPod to my computer. I've done this before using ephPod, however it didn't seem to work this time.

Does anyone know a free program that could do this? I've googled extensively, but I can't find  anything that's free (not a trial) and works.

Cheers

Comment: Doesn't iTunes do this?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick iTunes will promptly erase the iPod if it is not in the computer.

Comment: That or any of the free and/or open source alternatives like Songbird, Rhythmbox, gtkpod, Floola, Banshee, Amarok, Winamp, YamiPod, etc.

Comment: @HackToHell: Not if you manage your music manually as outlined here: http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-105068-itunes-wants-to-delete-all-my-songs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use iTunes and sync it using [this method](http://www.howtogeek.com/103754/how-to-sync-your-ipod-with-another-pc-without-losing-your-music/) so that you do not lose your files.