# Deactivate itunes to synchronize my ipod touch

Tags: itunes, ipod

What settings have I to do in iTunes to avoid changing my ipod clock ?

When I connected my ipod to PC, automatically iTunes starts and sync. During sync-ing, iTunes change my ipod clock.

How to avoid this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

[image: iTunes Device Preferences Dialog]

*(from a link in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/404540/52492) to another question)*